# How do I configure moving by and deleting words in ansi-term?

Tags: key-bindings, ansi-term

In ansi-term's "char run" mode, I can use <kbd>C-<left></kbd> and <kbd>C-<right></kbd> to move around in steps of one word, but as soon as I start typing again, the point moves back to where it was. They work fine in "line run" mode (<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd>).

How to I get the point to stay where I moved it?

Similarly, <kbd>C-w</kbd> seems to use a different definition of "word" than `backward-kill-word`, which I have also bound to <kbd>C-w</kbd> for normal buffers. For Instance, hitting <kbd>C-w</kbd> on the end of `ls /usr/local/bin` gives me `ls /usr/local/` in a scratch buffer, but in ansi-term it leaves me with `ls`.

Is there any way to configure these things more granularly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ansi-term's "char run mode", <kbd>C-<left></kbd> & co are by default intercepted by emacs, which moves the point instead of telling the undelying terminal to do it. This leads to the situation you describe: the point moves in the emacs buffer, but the next insertion will use the real cursor position in the terminal, which hasn't changed.

You thus need to reassign <kbd>C-<left></kbd> and <kbd>C-<right></kbd> to commands that actually forward the correct keys to the terminal:

```
(defun term-send-Cright () (interactive) (term-send-raw-string "\e[1;5C"))
(defun term-send-Cleft  () (interactive) (term-send-raw-string "\e[1;5D"))
(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-<right>")      'term-send-Cright)
(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-<left>")       'term-send-Cleft)
```

FYI, I found the `\e[1;5C` and `\e[1;5D` codes using the following trick:

1. run `cat >/dev/null` in a terminal
2. type <kbd>C-<left></kbd> and <kbd>C-<right></kbd> and see what is echoed back in the terminal
3. exit with <kbd>C-d</kbd> or <kbd>C-c</kbd>

Another way to find them would be to type in a terminal: <kbd>C-v</kbd><kbd>C-<left></kbd>

---

As for the <kbd>C-w</kbd> problem, it is of a different kind: as you said, emacs and bash do not have the same definition of what a word is. The only solution I would see would be to change one of them (either emacs or bash) to make it consistent with the other.

It looks like bash's default <kbd>M-<backspace></kbd> binding is closer to the behaviour of Emacs' `backward-kill-word`. You could thus bind <kbd>C-w</kbd> to a command which forwards the <kbd>M-<backspace></kbd>
key sequence to the terminal:

```
(defun term-send-Mbackspace () (interactive)(term-send-raw-string "\e\d"))
(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-w") 'term-send-Mbackspace)
```

Comment: I had to put in `"\eb"` and `"\ef"` (which is `^[b` for alt+left and `^[f` for alt+right). It works perfectly now. Being able to use `C-w` is *so* nice. Thanks :)

Comment: Note: In Emacs 24.4, I had to do this inside `(add-hook 'term-load-hook (lambda () ... )` because `term-raw-map` is not defined outside of this hook.

Comment: You're right: you need to delay evaluation until `term` is loaded. You could try wrapping everything in an `(eval-after-load "term" ...)` form: this should work for every emacs version.